# Question for technologies under NDA?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I was reading through [Hello world code for Mountain Lion OSX 10.8 showing notification like iChat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547997/hello-world-code-for-mountain-lion-osx-10-8-showing-notification-like-ichat). At the time the question was asked, the OS (Mountain Lion) and the technology (User Notifications) was under NDA from Apple.

One of the folks who tried to answer could not really provide a useful answer because of the NDA, and it appears he did the best he could with his hands tied. The answer generated a comment of "This is a useless answer. There are not examples on or linked from those pages."

Should these types of questions be closed while the technology is under NDA? Or is it expected the questions will wither and die on their own due to no answers? If they should be closed, then what is the appropriate reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, we do not close questions for being under NDA. **In fact**, we actively delete comments suggesting questions should be closed for such a reason, and reopen questions which get closed *for only that reason* (as in there's nothing else wrong with them).

**Read more:** [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors)