# Handling coursework help

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754888/including-two-separate-possibilities-in-a-while-loop-with-different-outcomes-p) (which has problems aside from the coursework) appeared yesterday, and it's clearly about GCSE Computing coursework. Ignoring other issues with the question, how should a coursework question be treated?

To be specific about that question (and I have done this course, and helped teach it), the [specification](http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/72936-specification.pdf) (section 4.2.2) for the course states:

> Candidates must work independently to produce their own final piece of work.

Therefore, if we answer the question, we provide a headache for the teacher, and make the student eligible for disqualification (unless he quotes the question as a research source, which is kind of stretching it). The other issue is that the coursework question is not publicly available, so SO might get into trouble for hosting "secret" information. Should we:

- Flag as `other`, and explain?
- Try to pick on something else in the post (E.G. not an mcve)?
- Give an answer such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014855/3946766)?
- Comment to remind the asker about quoting?

More samples:

- [code for my GCSE assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105169/code-for-my-gcse-assessment)
- [Javascript button click on event to run a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556830/javascript-button-click-on-event-to-run-a-function) (closed)
- [Error Message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513096/error-message-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-float) (closed)

Others can be found about A-level, etc. This is not the same as homework questions, as the coursework counts towards the final grade.

Comment: This is not a matter for Stack Overflow; if the course work is to be taken down the authorities governing the text can issue a DMCA takedown notice. We, the community cannot and should not police this.

Comment: As for homework questions, [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255477) applies, as well as the central [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811)

Comment: If you believe it is off-topic, then you can vote to close the question.  Do not flag using "Other", moderators will not step in to remove these questions, it is not our job to close and delete it.

Comment: Also related, about enforcement: [Question for technologies under NDA?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252216) and [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)

Comment: Also related - [Questions from Active Contests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258295/questions-from-active-contests)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, OK, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should judge the questions *by their merits alone*; if they are off-topic then vote to close them. If they are bad questions, vote them down.

We cannot and will not enforce third-party agreements, be they NDAs or coursework terms. See [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors), but to summarize:

- We are not party to the agreement the student is under.
- No moderator is equipped with the tools to police third-party agreements, and if they did so, could make Stack Exchange liable for all infringements.
- There is no way to verify any such claims, as the course work is, as you say, secret. I could go around accusing random posts of being GCSE course work and moderators would have no objective means to validate the claim.

You are free to comment on such questions, reminding the student of the terms of GCSE coursework.

The GCSE governing bodies would have to contact Stack Exchange themselves if they want to police such posts; there is a DMCA takedown procedure for copyrighted works.